# Posix/Perl regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have the simple regular expression:

```
\{[0-9]*\}
```

which works fine with PHP's ereg_ functions (Posix compatible), but I need to use the preg_match_all function, which doesn't have an ereg_ equivalent. My expression above doesn't seem to work with preg_ (perl compatible) functions. How can I go about "converting" it to be perl compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If im reading your regex correctly then just do this:

```
preg_match_all('/\{\d*?\}/'...);
```

`'/\{\d*?\}/'` will match an integer of any length.

Comment: I need any length of integer inside {} braces - sorry about that.

Comment: It looks like you're only matching a single digit.  To match the original posix regex, I believe you'd want /\{\d*\}/

Comment: \d matches and integer 1 is valid as is 99999999999999999999999

Comment: Uh, \d is shorthand for digit. It matches a single digit character, not an infinitely long integer. (Unless PHP does something really odd, which I doubt).